# Which PromQL function do I use to find the highest and lowest response time attained in a given time interval

Tags: prometheus, metrics, promql, grafana-loki

I would like to visualize the highest response time as well as the lowest response attained by an API in the last x minutes but I am not sure which PromQL I should be using exactly.

Currently I can scrape metrics and visualize the average response time (minute by minute) using :

```
sum(rate(request_duration_seconds_sum[1m]))/sum(rate(request_duration_seconds_count[1m]))
```

and the corresponding StatPanel :

[image: avg]

Now I want to design a similar StatPanel that will show **the highest response time that would have been recorded within the last minute** e.g if the scrape for the last minute has 7ms, 92ms, 6ms, 50ms then I want a panel that will show the highest response time attained i.e 92ms. Conversely the lowest response time Stat panel should show 7ms.

In my client instrumentation I have configured both a counter and a gauge as below :

```
public MetricReporter(ILogger<MetricReporter> logger)
{
    _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));

    _requestCounter = Metrics.CreateCounter("total_requests", "The total number of requests serviced by this API.");
    _requestGauge = Metrics.CreateGauge("total_requests_gauge", "The total number of requests serviced by this API.");

    _responseTimeHistogram = Metrics.CreateHistogram("request_duration_seconds",
        "The duration in seconds between the response to a request.", new HistogramConfiguration
        {
            Buckets = new[] { 0.01, 0.025, 0.05, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2.5, 5, 10  },
            LabelNames = new[] { "status_code", "method" , "path"}
        });
}
```

For this use case I cannot seem to find a working example *that shows these calculations when using a counter*.

I have tried using max_over_time with subquery as given [here](https://cloudinfrastack.com/blog/monitoring/using_prometheus_subquery_for_capturing_spikes/) but from my research I gather that the resultant calculation will be inaccurate (see comment [here](https://iximiuz.com/en/posts/prometheus-functions-agg-over-time/)).

As per Prometheus documentation functions min_over_time(), max_over_time(), avg_over_time(), ets *makes sense to use only with gauge metrics*.

Should I be using a gauge instead and if so how ?

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I have added a new panel that uses the histogram quantiles below but the resulting values are not correct ( *I made requests in a 1 minute interval and I had a max of 25ms (1st request) and another random one at 3ms*) :

```
histogram_quantile(1, increase(request_duration_seconds_bucket[1m]))
```

and this

```
histogram_quantile(0, increase(request_duration_seconds_bucket[1m]))
```

[image: quantile]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the stat panel, if you use the graph panel in Grafana then min, max, avg values are out of the box functionality. You can see them at the bottom right hand corner.

**update: adding queries and screenshot

Here is my query:

```
rate(http_server_requests_seconds_sum{job="",method="",namespace="",uri=""}[5m])
/
rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count{job="",method="",namespace="",uri=""}[5m])
```

Please see below:
[image]

to enable the min/max values in the legend - while editing the graph check the legend properties as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Would you share the corresponding PromQL for this type of Graph

Comment: Which version of Grafana are you using? I do not have a Graph panel in my instance. I only have the "Time Series" type and it does not show these averages out of the box. Is this a plugin or its default to your instance

Comment: We are on v7.5.17

Comment: I have updated the answer on how to enable min/max in the legend. Please check and mark this as the answer if it helped solve the problem.

Comment: I will look at it , plus one for the heads up. I am still trying to implement the GraphPanel because on my version it does not appear , I only have Time-Series.

Comment: Working now . eureka !!

Answer (score 1):

The `request_duration_seconds` is a [histogram](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#histogram) metric. That's why the maximum and the minimum response time must be calculated as 100th and 0th [percentile](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) over the histogram metric with the help of [histogram_quantile](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#histogram_quantile) function:

- The maximum `request_duration_seconds` value over the last 5 minutes:

```
histogram_quantile(1, increase(request_duration_seconds_bucket[5m]))
```

- The minimum `request_duration_seconds` value over the last 5 minutes:

```
histogram_quantile(0, increase(request_duration_seconds_bucket[5m]))
```

Note that the returned value are *estimations*. They can be far from the real minimum and maximum values if the minimum and maximum values are located too far from bucket boundaries configured for the histogram metric.

Side note: you can reduce the estimation error to around 5% in the worst case by using [VictoriaMetrics histograms](https://valyala.medium.com/improving-histogram-usability-for-prometheus-and-grafana-bc7e5df0e350). (I'm the author of VictoriaMetrics)

Comment: thanks , I have created a new panel with those two quantiles but I am not sure If its showing correct figures (highest response I observed was 25ms and lowest 3ms ) . I ran the test over a minute. Could it be the case that the "max and min values are located too far from the bucket boundaries". I have to look at MetricsQL then  . I have updated the question and added the visualization for this test ..

Comment: The returned min/max values are incorrect because the real minimum/max values are located too far from the configured bucket boundaries as I mentioned above. For example, if the real min value is lower than 0.01s and the lowest bucket has boundaries `0 - 0.01` like in the original question, then Prometheus has no any ability to determine the real min value, since all the values on this range go to this bucket. So it just returns the lowest boundary for this bucket - e.g. 0 - as the minimum estimated value (aka 0th percentile)